# Calculating height of item relative to location

Tags: iphone, algorithm, math, discrete-mathematics

I have an item which needs to be of height H1 at point P1 and H2 and point P2.
At any point between P1 and P2 the height needs to be somewhere between H1 and H2 relative to its distance from P1 and P2 (on straight line between them).

E.g.:
If H1 = 100 at P1 and H2 = 150 at P2, then on the mid-point between P1 and P2, the H = 125.

How do I calculate this?

Comment: Simple maths. Sorry, off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
H1 + (distanceOfPointFromP1/distanceOfP1AndP2)*(H2-H1)
```